# Android timer skipping numbers regularly

Tags: android, timer

I have an **android countdown timer** that is really inconsistent, and **doesn't update the GUI** regularly or correctly.

```
public boolean bTimerRunning = false;
public CountDownTimer timer;
private long currentTime = 180000;

public void onTimerTap(View v) {

    if (bTimerRunning) {
        //stop timer
        timer.cancel();
        bTimerRunning = false;

    } else {
        //start timer
        final TextView etTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

        //initalize Timer
        timer = new CountDownTimer(currentTime, 1000) {
            int secondsLeft = 0;
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                String currentTimeStr = String.format("%d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
                );

                //save value to "pause" timer
                currentTime = millisUntilFinished;

                //show on text
                etTime.setText(currentTimeStr);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };

        timer.start();
        //set boolean
        bTimerRunning = true;
    }



  }
```

From what I have seen in the past SO questions, this is typical for the last few seconds of the timer, but I'm seeing it in the first few ticks, or just in the middle. How can I make my timer a better ticker? Would narrowing down the tick time work and rounding?

Comment: is this problem occurring in a emulator or device?

Comment: yes, change 1000 to 500 for example

Comment: @pskink I changed it to 100, it still skips numbers

Comment: add Log.d then and see if onTick is called on regular basis

Comment: Looks like it is, I told it to log milliseconds and I get '167989|167879|167770'

Comment: so you cannot help much: onTick is called as expected but your system doesn't show the time from unknown reason

Comment: So is this a GUI updating problem instead? Is there some way for me to tell Android that this background thread will need regular GUI updates?